# What is the correct way to set expression with JasperReports API?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using text fields for displaying column names . For showing the corresponding name of the column I have tried the following method:

**Method 1:**

```
textField.setX(currentXPos);
textField.setY(0);
textField.setWidth(columnWidth);
textField.setPrintWhenDetailOverflows(false);
textField.setHeight(colDtlBandHeight);
textField.setStretchWithOverflow(true);
textField.setStretchType(StretchTypeEnum.RELATIVE_TO_BAND_HEIGHT);
textField.setStyle(normalFont);
textField.setBlankWhenNull(true);
JRDesignExpression  expression = new JRDesignExpression();
expression.setValueClass(columnClass);
expression.setText("$F{" + columnName + "}");
```

But on using the above method it throws an exception saying:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: 
1. Syntax error on token "ID", delete this token
   value = SHIFT ID; //$JR_EXPR_ID=44$
2. Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
   value = BILL NO.; //$JR_EXPR_ID=45$
3. Syntax error on token ".", invalid VariableDeclarator
   value = BILL NO.; //$JR_EXPR_ID=45$
4. Syntax error on token "DATE", delete this token
   value = BILL DATE; //$JR_EXPR_ID=46$
```

But on using the below lines the column Names are set correctly .

Method 2:

```
textField.setExpression(new JRDesignExpression("new String(\""+colTitle+"\")"));
```

My doubts are: 
1. For displaying the data the first method mentioned is used . Then how come there are no exceptions in that case ? 
2. Why did it throw those exceptions when the same method was used for displaying column names? 
3. How did the 2nd method work ?

Answer (score 0):

**1.:**

I suppose the data is properly enclosed in quotes.

**2.:**

Judging by the exception explanation (e.g. `Syntax error on token "ID", delete this token`) the interpreter sees two values, `SHIFT` and `ID`. It seems here that quotes are missing, e.g.

```
"SHIFT ID"
"BILL NO."
```

**3.:**

In your first example, you create a **JRDesignExpression**, set the value class and set the text.

The field isn't enclosed in quotes as seen in your lower example. It should look like this:

```
expression.setText("\"$F{" + columnName + "}\"");
```

Also, you didn't assign the expression to your textField:

```
textField.setExpression(expression)
```